# Import script stop with error 500 after 10 - 15 min - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, error, import

I'm using magento CE 1.9.1.
 
I made an import script to import products from my xml provider but i have an issue. 
When i run my script, it crash after 10 - 15 min with an error 500. So i have only 200 - 250 products imported while they are 400+ in the xml.
I have already increased max_execution_time and memory_limit in my php.ini and .htaccess and set values in my script, so i think my problem is in my script but i didn't find it.
Someone could help me ?

Here my code :

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 1200);

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$file = 'feed.xml'; 

$feed = simplexml_load_file($file);


foreach($feed as $product){

    //values in xml
    $sku = $product->identifiant_unique;
    $prix = $product->prix;
    $categorie1 = $product->categorie1;
    $categorie2 = $product->categorie2;
    $titre = $product->categorie3;
    $sexe = $product->sexe;
    $matiere = $product->matiere;
    $marque = $product->marque;
    $couleur = $product->couleur;
    $taille = $product->taille;
    $quantiteStock = $product->quantiteStock;
    $image = $product->photo_produit_grande;
    $small_image = $product->photo_produit_medium;
    $thumbnail = $product->photo_produit_petite;
    $stock = $product->stock;
    $poid = $product->poids_net;
    $model_code = $product->modele_code;
    $tendance = $product->tendance;
    $univers = $product->univers;
    $coll = $product->collection;



    //Setters 
    $produit = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $produit->setName($titre.' '.$sku);
    $produit->setSku($sku);
    $produit->setWeight($poid);
    $produit->setAttributeSetId(4);
    $produit->setDescription($titre.' '.$sku);
    $produit->setShortDescription($titre.' '.$sku);
    $produit->setTypeId($product['type_id'])->setWebsiteIds(array(1))->setStatus(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
    $produit->setMatiere($matiere);
    $produit->setSexe($sexe);
    $produit->setMarque($marque);
    $produit->setTendance($tendance);
    $produit->setUnivers($univers);
    $produit->setColl($coll);
    $produit->setModelcode($model_code);
    setOrAddOptionAttribute($produit, 'color', $couleur);
    setOrAddOptionAttribute($produit, 'taille', $taille);
    $produit->setPrice($prix);
    if($categorie1 == "Bijoux Fantaisie" && $categorie2 == "Bracelet"){

        $produit->setCategoryIds(array(2,7,19));

    }else if($categorie1 == "Bijoux Fantaisie" && $categorie2 == "Collier"){

        $produit->setCategoryIds(array(2,7,18));

    }else if($categorie1 == "Bijoux Fantaisie" && $categorie2 == "Boucle d'oreilles"){

        $produit->setCategoryIds(array(2,7,20));

    }else if($categorie1 == "Bijoux Fantaisie" && $categorie2 == "Bague"){

        $produit->setCategoryIds(array(2,7,21));

    }else if($categorie1 == "Argent 925" && $categorie2 == "Bracelet"){

        $produit->setCategoryIds(array(2,4,15));

    }else if($categorie1 == "Argent 925" && $categorie2 == "Collier"){

        $produit->setCategoryIds(array(2,4,14));

    }else if($categorie1 == "Argent 925" && $categorie2 == "Boucle d'oreilles"){

        $produit->setCategoryIds(array(2,4,16));

    }else if($categorie1 == "Argent 925" && $categorie2 == "Bague"){

        $produit->setCategoryIds(array(2,4,17));

    }else{

        $produit->setCategoryIds(array(2,3));
    }

    $produit->setIsMassupdate(true);
    $produit->setExcludeUrlRewrite(true);
    $produit->save();

    $prodid = $prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);
    $colourId = $prodid->getResource()->getAttribute("color")->getSource()->getOptionId($couleur);
    $prodid->setColor($colourId)->save();


    // For Inventory Management
    $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');
    $stockItem->assignProduct($produit);
    $stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 1);
    $stockItem->setData('stock_id', 1);
    $stockItem->setData('store_id', 1);
    $stockItem->setData('manage_stock', 1);
    $stockItem->setData('use_config_manage_stock', 0);
    $stockItem->setData('min_sale_qty', 1);
    $stockItem->setData('use_config_min_sale_qty', 0);
    $stockItem->setData('max_sale_qty', 1000);
    $stockItem->setData('use_config_max_sale_qty', 0);
    $stockItem->setData('qty', $quantiteStock);
    $stockItem->save();



    $sku = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku);

    $url = $image;

    $image_type = substr(strrchr($url,"."),1); //find the image extension
    $filename   = $sku.'.'.$image_type; //give a new name, you can modify as per your requirement
    $filepath   = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import'. DS . $filename; //path for temp storage folder: ./media/import/

    file_put_contents($filepath, file_get_contents(trim($url))); //store the image from external url to the temp storage folder


        $mediaAttribute = array (   'image',
                                    'small_image',
                                    'thumbnail',
                                );

    $prod->addImageToMediaGallery($filepath, $mediaAttribute, true, false);

    $prod->save();

    if($produit->save()){
        echo "Le produit ".$sku." a été crée<br>";

     }

}

function setOrAddOptionAttribute($product, $arg_attribute, $arg_value) {
    $attribute_model = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute');
    $attribute_options_model = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table');
    $attribute_code = $attribute_model->getIdByCode('catalog_product', $arg_attribute);
    $attribute = $attribute_model->load($attribute_code);
    $attribute_options_model->setAttribute($attribute);
    $options = $attribute_options_model->getAllOptions(false);
    $value_exists = false;
    foreach($options as $option) {
        if ($option['label'] == $arg_value) {
            $value_exists = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // if this option does not exist, add it.
    if (!$value_exists) {
        $attribute->setData('option', array(
            'value' => array(
                'option' => array($arg_value,$arg_value)
            )
        ));
        $attribute->save();
    }

    $product->setData($arg_attribute, $arg_value);
}  

?>
```

Thanks

EDIT :

When i don't set the max_execution_time in my script i have this error in my php log:
 `Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in website\lib\Zend\Cache\Backend\File.php on line 1028`

like it ignore the max_execution_time value in both php.ini and .htaccess but when i set my max_execution_time value, no error appears in the php error log

line 1028 in File.php :
  `protected function _fileNameToId($fileName)
    {
        $prefix = $this->_options['file_name_prefix'];
        return preg_replace('~^' . $prefix . '---(.*)$~', '$1', $fileName);
    }`

EDIT 2 : 
When i activate the debug mode, i have this error :
 `Recoverable Error: Object of class Mage_Catalog_Model_Product could not be converted to string`

The line correspond to `$filename = $sku.'.'.$image_type;`

Comment: My gut is telling me its a memory leak but at this point thats just speculation. To really know what the problem is you will need to look at your php error log to find what is causing the 500 error. Perhaps if you add the error to your question then someone will be able to help more.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing $product into your loop like this. It saves memory by not cloning the object but, rather, passing in the actual object. I use this alot when I am working with large collections that are taxing on the memory.

```
foreach($feed as &$product){
}
```

If that doesn't solve the problem, you should still keep it in there as it will save you a bit of memory.

Additionally, this does not always work, sometime you will get an error regarding passing by reference with an iterator, it all depends whats going on inside of the loop and what's going on within the functions being called inside the loop.

Another thing you should be considering is that for every line, you are setting data like this:

```
$produit->setMatiere($matiere);
$produit->setSexe($sexe);
$produit->setMarque($marque);
$produit->setTendance($tendance);
$produit->setUnivers($univers);
```

This means that for every single line of every iteration of the loop, a variety of Varien_Object methods are being called. It would be less taxing if you were to construct an array and then pass it to the object like this:

```
$array = array(
    'matiere'  => $matiere,
    'sexe'     => $sexe,
    'marque'   => $marque,
    'tendance' => $tendance,
    'univers'  => $univers
    // add the remainder of your elements here
);

// If you want to add this data to the product but also keep any other data that already exists on the product
$produit->addData($array);

// Or if you want to make the array the only data on the product object
$product->setData($array);
```

If you have a look at the Varien_Object class, within the `setData` method, all thats happening when you pass in an array is this:

```
$this->_data = $key;
$this->_addFullNames();
```

However, when you call `setData` on every single line, you are doing this each time:

```
$this->_data[$key] = $value;
if (isset($this->_syncFieldsMap[$key])) {
    $fullFieldName = $this->_syncFieldsMap[$key];
    $this->_data[$fullFieldName] = $value;
}
```

So the moral of the story is, you can create an array and the call upon `setData/addData` one within each loop rather than calling upon `$produit->setData($key, $value)` 50+ times in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Hi Shawn,  When i test your solution my loop doesn't start and i have this php fatal error :  `An iterator cannot be used with foreach by reference `

Comment: Answer update, thanks for letting me know the result of my first idea.

Comment: I should have also mentioned that methods like `$produit->setMatiere($matiere)` don't actually exist. The method name is first analyzed and then converted to `$produit->setData('matiere',$matiere)` so thats just additional work for the server.

Comment: @JulienDelac if my answer worked for you or got you going in the right direction, please accept it so that I may get my reputation points, its been a while. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your log's folder of your server, and monitor the error.log when the 500 error occurs, this gives you information exactly why its giving you a error. Possibly indeed your memory or something.

Its not a fix but a work-a-round would be to maybe do it in batches.